# Verbatim Frame Incompatibility

Tags: verbatim

It's driving me nuts that using `verbatim` causes the `\end{frame}` statement to throw an error. How do I fix this?

LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item An item
            \begin{verbatim}
            some code
            \end{verbatim}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
```

This is supposed to work like that but it doesn't.

Comment: you need `[fragile]` option on the frame

Comment: And don't indent the `\end{frame}`. Beside this: It is *not* supposed to work like this. See e.g. "12.9 Verbatim and Fragile" Text in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks guys, with `[fragile]` and no indentation it works now. Can I have indentation still somehow?

Comment: The `\end{frame}` must in this case be alone and at the begin of the line.